# Hide/ Unhide sections on button click in elementor form

Tags: wordpress, show-hide, elementor

I am creating a form in elementor using the form, I have a radio button by clicking it, some of the fields should unhide. How do I achieve it?

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is to correctly name the IDs in your elementor form.

Please name radio button's ID with `same_as_shipping_address`.

And in CONTENT -> Options please write this:

```
Same as shipping address|same_as_shipping_address
Ohters options 1|other_option_1 /* You have to write your own option */
```

Elementor will then create an input that will have a selector:

```
input[name="form_fields[same_as_shipping_address]"]
```

Then for all the elements to hide when the radio button is selected, give them an ID with `_show_if_same_as_shipping_address` at the end.

For example for the phone (if it has to be hidden) the ID will be `phone_number_show_if_same_as_shipping_address`

Elementor will then create a div with it as a class:

```
.elementor-field-group-phone_number_show_if_same_as_shipping_address
```

Now the goal is to check each change of `input[name="form_fields[same_as_shipping_address]"]` and display the fields that have like an ID with `_show_if_same_as_shipping_address` at the end.

We are going to use a jQuery script to do this.

If you don't have child theme, create one and use this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var radio = $('input[name="form_fields[same_as_shipping_address');
  var toToggle = $("div[class*=_show_if_same_as_shipping_address]");

  /* By default */
  onRadioChange();

  /* Function triggered when the visitor changes the status of the sending address */
  radio.on("change", function (e) {
    onRadioChange();
  });

  /* Action to be carried out */
  function onRadioChange() {
    if (getRadioVal()=== "same_as_shipping_address") {
      toToggle.css('display', 'flex');
    }
    else {
      toToggle.css('display', 'none');
    }
  }

  function getRadioVal() {
    return $('input[name="form_fields[same_as_shipping_address:checked').val();
  }
});
```